# Limit the visibility of records related list

Tags: administration, related-list, visibility

I have a custom object `Obj__c` where I have created a custom lookup field to Account.

In the Account layout I have an `Obj__c` related list showing the `Obj__c` records related to a particular Account.

What I wish to achieve is to hide certain records in the related list.

For instance:
- if the Account status is set to *Active* hide all `Obj__c` records with status *Closed*
- if the Account status is set to *Inactive* hide all `Obj__c` records with status *Open*.

Is it possible to hide records in related list based on the status of the parent record and how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Related lists cannot be filtered this way. You could create a custom component or Visualforce page, or build a solution involving record types, multiple page layouts, multiple lookup fields, and a few triggers or processes.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but your request is now possible thanks for the **Dynamic Related List - Single** component in a Lightning Record Page .

You simply place the component on the record page and choose the filters you want on the right side, where it says **Related List Filters**. Of course this is only available for internal users who can see lightning pages, so you can't do this in Lightning Experience, for example.